# Rudin Ch.11 Exc 11: proof check

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

**The exercise.** Denote the space of all Lebesgue integrable functions on $X$ as $L(\mu)$ i.e. finite Lebesgue integral. Suppose $f,g \in L(\mu).$ Define the distance function $$d(f,g) = \int_X |f-g| d\mu.$$

Show that $L(\mu)$ is a complete metric space i.e. all Cauchy sequences are convergent.

**My proof.** (Skip the proof of $d$ is a metric). Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $N$ such that $m,n \geq N$ implies that $\int_X |f_n - f_m| d\mu < \epsilon$. Fix $m \geq N$.

Define $g(x) = \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ pointwise. We first show that $\liminf_{n\to \infty} |f_m(x) - f_n(x)| = |f_m(x) - g(x)|$. By definition of limit inferior, there exists $T$ such that if $n\geq T$, then $ 0\leq g(x) - f_n(x) < \epsilon$, and there exists a subsequence such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_{n_k}(x) = g(x)$. Hence, if $n\geq T$, then $$|f_m(x) - g(x)| - |f_m(x) - f_n(x)| \leq |g(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon.$$
Furthermore, for large enough $k$, $$||f_m(x) - f_{n_k}(x)| - |f_m(x) - g(x)|| \leq |g(x) - f_{n_k}(x)| < \epsilon, \text{ so } \lim_{k\to \infty} |f_m(x) - f_{n_k}(x)| = |f_m(x) - g(x)|.$$

By Fatou's lemma, we have $$\int_{X} \liminf_{n\to\infty} |f_m(x) - f_n(x)| = \int_X |f_m(x) - g(x)| \leq \liminf_{n \to\infty} \int_X |f_m(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon.$$

Hence, if $m \geq N$, then $d(f_m, g) < \epsilon$. Also, $g \in L(\mu)$ because $g-f_m \in L(\mu)$ and $f_m \in L(\mu)$, so $g = g-f_m + f_m \in L(\mu)$. From this follows completeness.

**I checked other proofs of this, but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong with my proof. Could someone help me in checking my proof? It seems alright to me... thank you!**

Comment: can anyone provide a check?